# Why does it say "that player is offline" when that player is most certainly online?

Tags: diablo-iii

Every now and then, I try to be social when playing *Diablo 3*. I like to send friendly messages to friends in an attempt to solicit a reaction that I will find humorous.

However, very recently, I started receiving messages any time I would send someone a tell. The message reads "That player is offline."

[image: spugly plz]
<sup>spugly plz</sup>

The issue here is that... The user very clearly *isn't* offline. I am now unsure as to whether or not my message went through.

**Are my messages still going through? If not, how can I fix  this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did a search for this issue and found several people facing the same problem.

You can read the official Bug Report posted on the [Battle.Net forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151267856).

Your messages are still going through, but will still see this message randomly. It's been reported but so far there is no fix.

Comment: In my experience, whispers are **not** going through when this error crops up.