# I appear to be offline when I'm online

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it say “that player is offline” when that player is most certainly online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68091/why-does-it-say-that-player-is-offline-when-that-player-is-most-certainly-onli)

My friends are telling me that I appear as "offline" in their friends lists while playing Diablo 3. I can join up with them, quest with them, trade with them, talk to them, and I am most definitely online.

I opened up my social window and the icon in the top left shows that I'm "offline" or gray icon. So I switch it to the "online" or green icon. This does nothing, as each time I open the social window, it's back to "offline".

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have "hide online activity" selected?

Comment: I was unaware of such an option. I tried looking for it. Where can I find it?

Comment: I'm getting this also and it is very frustrating. I've check everywhere i can think of to find a setting that will change this.
But i fear it is a bug.
Any help would be much appreciated.